# two identical strings are not equal python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
 def login():
    contents = {}
    with open("pwdFile.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
        split = line.split("|")
        contents[split[0]]= ",".join(split[1:])
      if userName.get() in contents:
        print("Username exist")
        if contents[userName.get()] == pwd.get():
          print("logged in")


print(contents)
print(contents[userName.get()])
print(pwd.get())
```

This code is reading from a file to check if the stored password in the file matches the password that is inputted.Both passwords are identical however they do not match therefore the if contetns == pwd.get is not executed.I am using tkinter and getting pwd from an Entry() and passing it to the login() function.

Here is the text file its reading from:
james|pwd

Comment: Why do you think they're identical?

Comment: because the output of  contents[userName.get()] and pwd.get() which is printed at the bottom is identical

Comment: That's not what you're code proves. Your code proves that they *look* identical upon visual inspection.

Comment: would it be something to do with using \n for a new line after the password is written to the file?

Comment: I would suggest printing the `repr` of your strings, which will put quotation  marks around them (making whitespace more apparent) and escape any special characters.

Comment: Thankyou blckknght. it was due to \n being present on the password from the contents.

Answer (score 1):

You have whitespaces at the end of each line, so they end up in `pwd`.
Get rid of them using:

```
pwd.strip()
```

Note that it might not work well if it's possible any password contains leading or trailing whitespaces, but you shouldn't have plain text passwords anyways, right?

Comment: thank! il try it now

Comment: its one of my first projects at uni building it up stage by stage. Password encryption is the next hurdle

Comment: Then you should be good if you ensure hashes you get for them don't use whitespaces.